# Java, class, Boolean, logic mess

Tags: java, string, class, boolean, logic

So, we were given to code this ScantronGrader for homework, and the specs say that we have to create this class `isValid` to check to validity of the options that fall into either A, B, C, or D (all uppercase), I first tried `switch` (error), `if-else-if` (error); `do-while` (Oh, I know so wrong and error). I tried `for` loop first, and the value didn't get incremented.

In its recent rendition, this is my issue. TBH, I don't even know what I am doing anymore.

```
public static boolean isValid(String inputstr)
    {
        int x = 0;
        do
        {
            switch (inputstr.charAt(x))
            {
            case 'A':
            case 'B':
            case 'C':
            case 'D':
                return true;
        default: return false;
        x++;    
            }
        } while (x < inputstr.length());
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that it is not letting me increment the counter. Now, I need to do that, else, how would I shift right? Either way, please HALP.

Comment: `"TBH, I don't even know what I am doing anymore"` -- I feel your pain, but in this situation what you want to do is get up with your instructor or a knowledgeable fellow student for intense one-on-one help.

Comment: you need to have check either outside of static method or have it as attribute of of dynamic class. statement "return" end the operation so everything after is not executed. You can use try-finally. But, most importantly, you can use a good tutor on java and coding.

Comment: Could you provide an example of an input and expected output? It isn't quite clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you! This is my very first semester, actually. My major is actually Statistics, but apparently, it was a requirement. I figure I might as well pay attention rather than steal homework. I need to steer right b/c The grades are entered in the format AbcDX.... So, basically, I'm checking for every value in the string. The output basically shows that the value X is invalid. Which is the purpose of this method. And I am at sea.

Comment: So you need to check if in a String say (ABCDX) there is an occurrence of X? If yes then you want to return false? Is that the requirement?

Comment: That is the general idea, yes.

Comment: Just because the char at the x'th position is valid, does not mean the entire string is - the return true there is wrong, you'll want to break from the switch and return true after the loop if no invalid character has been found.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood what that method have to do, but if it has to return  true only if the string have those letter you can do this:

```
public static boolean isValid(String inputstr)
{
    int x = 0;
    boolean bool = true;
    do
    {
        if(!(inputstr.charAt(x) == 'A' || inputstr.charAt(x) == 'B' || inputstr.charAt(x) == 'C' || inputstr.charAt(x) == 'D'))
    {
        bool = false;
    }
    x++;
    }while (x < inputstr.length());
    return bool;
}
```

Comment: it has to count letters. If it returns, the counter is lost :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after some ideas from here (Thank you for reaching out to help), I am toying with this one which seems to work. Just let me know if I am doing anything unnecessary/ useless, or there is a more efficient way to do this, please?

```
public static boolean isValid(String inputstr) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < inputstr.length(); x++) {
            switch (inputstr.charAt(x)) {
            case 'A':
            case 'B':
            case 'C':
            case 'D':
            break;
            default: count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will return false for Strings without 'X' as well. Eg (ABCDLWE, ABCDL, etc)